# 2G preferred network type on Android 13

Tags: mobile-network, 2g, android-13

I'm using a crDroid [rom](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-13-crdroid-android-9-x-for-samsung-galaxy-s8-s8-n8.4516883/) on a Samsung S8 phone and I have realized that google [decided to fight 2G](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2022/01/victory-google-releases-disable-2g-feature-new-android-smartphones) networks.

I have only 3G and 4G options for preferred network type now in the rom settings. And if I use a method that [worked beautifully](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213759/network-mode-switch-quick-settings-tile) on android pie, it no longer works on android 13. When I set the type to 2G, the network type doesn't  change and the rom settings displays something like "invalid value, defaulting to 4G".

But I found out I can still change it by using the phone app, inputting `*#*#4636#*#*` and then selecting 2G. This way 2G is even displayed in the rom settings and it works. But as soon as I change it to 4G, the only way to get back to 2G is to input the code again in the phone app.

I would like to have some automation to switch between 2G and 4G. Preferrably with a quick settings tile.

So, is there a way to achieve this in a more effective way?

Comment: Not sure if this can work at all but may be worth a try: create tel link in a web page: `tel://*#*#4636#*#*`.

Comment: didn't try that, but I guess opening the UI for selecting the preferred mode could be implemented using Tasker, for example. What I'd like to achieve is not using the UI at all.

Comment: For a Tasker solution, see [this](https://uk.moyens.net/how-to/how-to-change-preferred-network-type-with-tasker-no-root/). Works on my Android 10 with root. See if it works on your device.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try granting the adb permission later, but without it I get this error when trying the Mobile network type task. Looks like it's not because of permissions, but I'll check later. The error: 17.15.04/Ew add wait type EasyAction1 time 2147483647
17.15.04/Ew add wait type EasyAction1 done
17.15.04/E add wait task
17.15.04/E Error: 1
17.15.04/E Unfortunately Google disabled this feature for apps that target Android 10 and above (d1).

Comment: Firelord, if you don't mind me asking - did you grant the permissions with ADB?

Comment: The article lists possible threats and then "And that’s why you can perform tasks in Tasker that previously required root permission.", so I wonder if these permissions are really required if I have root.

Answer (score -1):

No. `*#*#4636#*#*` is the only way.

Comment: I guess there are no commands that could be input to the dialer and would change 2G/4G directly, without additional clicks in the screen that *#*#4636#*#* opens?

Comment: That code merely opens a UI. The modifications the UI provides may be available via API or via a custom hack in some files/databases. It is about giving it an honest try, document the attempts and then make an assertion that the above code is the only way. It is like saying brightness can only be changed through Settings app. That it is the only way. But we all know that's not true.

Comment: Exactly, in my comment I was wondering maybe adding some symbols to the code that opens the UI could execute the command directly, without using the UI.